# Python azure function with app insights dependancy tracking

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage, appinsights

I have a python azure function, that gets data from blob storage.

```
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:    
    default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True)
    blob_storage_uri = "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net"

    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(blob_storage_uri, credential=default_credential)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("my-container")
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("files/stefan/my_file.json")
    blob_data = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
    return func.HttpResponse(blob_data, status_code=200)
```

I want to track getting data from blob storage with app insights dependencies:

[image]

my host.json looks like that:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "enableDependencyTracking": true,
      "dependencyTrackingOptions": {
        "enableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation": true
      },
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request;Exception;Dependency"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

What else should I do?

Comment: with  [sample code](https://i.imgur.com/6LfslsM.png)  able to  [get](https://i.imgur.com/fot3ifu.png)  dependency [tracking](https://i.imgur.com/AzLumv4.png) in  [app insights](https://i.imgur.com/UPqzDC3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Followed this documation [Dependency tracking in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies)  .
- Dependency tracking in Application Insights tracks the length of dependency calls, whether they succeed or fail, and other details like the dependence's name.
- used Azure Blob Storage  name in `log_dependency`
- The `log_dependency` logs an Azure Blob Storage dependency with target `"sampath23.blob.core.windows.net"` and name `"get_blob"` and correlate them to requests and exceptions.

**Sample code to Set up Dependency Tracking:**

```py
import  logging
import  azure.functions  as  func
from  applicationinsights  import  TelemetryClient
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient
instrumentation_key = '57596d9d-e36c-4d39-bb87-19250c7c2812'
tc = TelemetryClient(instrumentation_key)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
def  log_dependency(dependency_type,  target,  name,  success=True,  duration=None):
tc.track_dependency(dependency_type,  target,  name,  success,  duration)
tc.flush()
def  log_to_blob(log_data):
try:
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=sampath23;AccountKey=KyJusUk7qzr9lZQGVfJs2kdCbMNK+ASt0aYv9w==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client('sampath')
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client('function-logs1')
blob_client.upload_blob(log_data)
logging.info("Log data uploaded to Azure Blob Storage.")
except  Exception  as  e:
logging.exception("Error while uploading log data to Blob Storage: " + str(e))
def  main(req:  func.HttpRequest)  ->  func.HttpResponse:
try:
log_dependency("Azure Blob Storage",  "sampath23.blob.core.windows.net",  "get_blob")
log_to_blob("Function execution output")
return  func.HttpResponse("Function executed successfully.")
except  Exception  as  e:
tc.track_exception()
return  func.HttpResponse("Function failed.",  status_code=500)
```

[image]
[image]

**In Azure Application Insights:**

[image]

- Azure Function to retrieve data from an Azure Blob Storage container and uses Application Insights to monitor and [track dependencies](https://i.imgur.com/ji3Nedf.png) and exceptions.

**To trace Dependency:**

```py
def  main(req:  func.HttpRequest)  ->  func.HttpResponse:
try:
connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=sampath23;AccountKey=Ky;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("sampath")
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("function-logs")
blob_data = blob_client.download_blob().readall() 
tc.track_dependency("Azure Blob Storage",  blob_client.url,  "get_blob")
return  func.HttpResponse(blob_data,  status_code=200)
except  Exception  as  e:
tc.track_exception()
return  func.HttpResponse("Error occurred.",  status_code=500)
```

[image]

[image]

- For more details refer Dependency tracking in [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies)  with [OpenCensus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python-dependency) .

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working. But is it possible to enable dependency logs by `host.json`?

Comment: yes  with```"enableDependencyTracking": true``` according to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#enable-sql-query-collection)